# C# database compare one Date/Time field from a table with today

Tags: c#, database, datetime

To make the story short I have a table inside of which I have a column of type Date/Time. I used MS Acces 2013 to create the database. Now, I need at a certain point in my app to check and delete all the records that are having their date smaller than today. Let's say that `conn` is my connection to my database. I wrote:

```
conn.Open(); 
string delRec = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myDateTimeColumn < '" + DateTime.Now + "'";
ExecQuery(delRec);
conn.Close();
```

If I replace the string with, let's say:

```
string delRec = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE anIntColumn < 21";
```

everything is running just fine. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built in Now() function:

```
string delRec = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myDateTimeColumn < Now()";
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS is not recognizing as a date passed in WHERE clause.

```
conn.Open();
string delRec = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myDateTimeColumn < '#" + DateTime.Now + "#'";
ExecQuery(delRec);
conn.Close();
```

There may be one more point to check that are you passing same date format in where clause parameter. e.g 'YYYY/MM/DD'

Can you try this one. Hope this will help

Comment: Nope, it does not work with the string that you suggested. As for the format, it's the same as it is in my DB. I even MessageBox.Show() it (I mean the delRec string) to check the query. Is the same date format. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DateTime.Now.Day method
i.e.

`conn.Open();
string delRec = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myDateTimeColumn < '" + DateTime.Now.Day + "'";
ExecQuery(delRec);
conn.Close();`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Tried that before. No success. Simon's answer works perfect. Thanks for answering, though...